# Is int() ok with newlines and spaces?

Tags: python, string, int

I try the following and it prints 1 with no exception. 
Is this an expected behaviour for all versions (>2.7) of python?

```
a='1 \r\n'
print int(a)
```

Comment: Why do you expect an exception?

Comment: Yes, that's expected behaviour.

Comment: Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int for the Python versions you are interested in (use the version picker at the top left of the page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for `int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) explicitly states this is expected behaviour:

> If *x* is not a number or if base is given, then I must be a string or Unicode object representing an integer literal in radix base. Optionally, the literal can be preceded by + or - (with no space in between) and **surrounded by whitespace)**.

Emphasis mine.

This is the expected behaviour for Python; the first version where you could pass string to the `int()` function was [Python 1.5](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5/lib/node26.html#1511), and the behaviour has remained unchanged in Python 2 and Python 3.